# How to fix infinite scroll javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make infinite scroll loads data with below script. Initial data loads correctly but seems like no scroll is detected. I've tried adding alert to debug but I can't seem to find the problem. Backend page **p_load.php** is working fine. Any idea what might be the issue?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var track_load = 0; //total loaded record group(s)
    var loading  = false; //to prevents multipal ajax loads
    var total_groups = 2; //total record group(s)   

    $('#result').load("p_load.php?t=", {'group_no':track_load}, function() {track_load++;}); //load first group

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            alert("Detected scrolling"); //not working
            if(track_load <= total_groups && loading==false) //there's more data to load
            {
                loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image

                //load data from the server using a HTTP POST request
                $.post('p_load.php?t=',{'group_no': track_load}, function(data){

                    $("#result").append(data); //append received data into the element

                    //hide loading image
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image once data is received

                    track_load++; //loaded group increment
                    loading = false; 

                }).fail(function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //any errors?

                    alert(thrownError); //alert with HTTP error
                    $('.animation_image').hide(); //hide loading image
                    loading = false;

                });

            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
  $(document).on('scroll', function () {
    if(window.scrollY + window.innerHeight >= document.body.scrollHeight) {
        //your code
    };
  });
```

Comment: Tried both (outside **ready** function and your modification with **scrollY**). No luck. Simple alert wont work. :(

Comment: Do you see the scrolling line on the right on the window? Maybe your CSS sets "overflow: hidden" somewhere. Please try $(document).on('scroll', function () instead of $(window).

Comment: Problem fixed. It should be inside **ready** function as original. Only it should monitor **$(document).scroll(** as you suggested. Please edit answer in order to mark it completed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the Intersection Observer API, that is what it is for.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API